How to maintain all geometry when exporting to .obj
I have a 3D model where I’m adding specific properties to create a hierarchical structure based on these properties. My goal is to retain this hierarchy and all individual geometries when exporting the model as a .obj file, as it will be used in Autodesk Forge. However, I'm facing challenges in achieving this.
I tried using the "Material Groups" option during export, creating a unique material for each property and assigning it to objects with matching property names. This approach preserved the hierarchy in the .obj file based on the properties. However, it also merged all geometries with the same material into a single, larger geometry, which I want to avoid.
Is there a way to retain both the hierarchy and the individual geometries in the .obj file format?
